# bootstrap 4 dropdown opening issue

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have just update bootstrap to v4 and now in my angular 5 application I have an issue with dropdown menu.
I need to click twice to open the menu the first time I want to open it, after that it works well.

[image]

This is the code:

```
<div class="dropdown col-md-2 offset-md-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-info dropdown-toggle float-right" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <i class="material-icons">build</i>
     <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li (click)="print()">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{'refund.detail.actions.print' | translate }}</a>
    </li>
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailModal" (click)="setEmailData()">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{'movement.detail.actions.email' | translate }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have no error in console.
Can someone help me to understand this incorrect behavior?

Comment: It could be easier to use an Angular implementation of the Bootstrap code, like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found the solution importing packages in the `angular.cli.json` file in this order:

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"
```

Now I don't see any kind of opening issue.